# If $t \mapsto \mu((-\infty, t))$ is differentiable at $x$, and $a_n \nearrow x$, does $\mu(\{a_n\})/(x-a_n)$ tend to zero?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, measure-theory, derivatives

Let $\mu$ be a complex (and therefore finite) Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}$ and suppose we have a function $f(t)=\mu((-\infty,t))$. Further suppose that $f$ is differentiable at a point $x\in\mathbb{R}$.
Now suppose we have a strictly increasing sequence $a_n \nearrow x$. Does it necessarily follow that $\frac{\mu(\{a_n\})}{x-a_n}\rightarrow 0$?

I've been trying to prove this for some time but to no avail and I'm now beginning to suspect it's untrue. I've also tried to construct a counterexample but every time it breaks differentiability of $f$ at $x$ but I can't work out why this would always be the case. Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. First, we can simplify the notation and the typing by assuming $x=0$.
And also wlog $f(0)=0$. (If you don't see why that last bit is wlog, take the proof below and rewrite it without that assumption.)

Now since $\mu$ is continuous from above, being finite, $$\mu(\{a_n\})=\lim_{\delta\to0+}\mu([a_n,a_n+\delta))=\lim_{\delta\to0+}(f(a_n+\delta)-f(a_n)).$$ So if $\delta_n>0$ is small enough we have
$$\left|\frac{\mu(\{a_n\})}{a_n}\right|\le2\left|\frac{f(a_n+\delta_n)-f(a_n)}{a_n}\right|.$$Now if $\delta_n$ is small enough we also have $0\ne a_n+\delta_n\to0$, so $$\frac{f(a_n+\delta_n)}{a_n+\delta_n}\to f'(0).$$ Certainly $f(a_n)/a_n\to f'(0)$, so we need only show that if $\delta_n$ is small enough then $$\frac{f(a_n+\delta_n)}{a_n+\delta_n}-\frac{f(a_n+\delta_n)}{a_n}\to0.$$This is easy; play with the fractions to see how small is small enough. (Note that $f$ is bounded in some neighborhood of $0$.)

Comment: Thanks! The step I was missing was the realising the limit which describes $\mu (\{a_n\})$

Comment: That's sort of one of the basic things about how these things work. The function $f$ has bounded variation, so it's continuous except for jump discontinuities at countably many points. In fact $f$ is continuous at $a$ if and only if $\mu(\{a\})=0$; if $\mu(\{a\})\ne0$ it is the size of the jump in $f$ at $a$.